# Potential Leak, assigning NSString-Property to UILabel

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

When I analyze my code it shows up a potential leak when I assign a Core Data String-attribute to a UILabel

cell.textLabel.text = prop.new_value;

Running the App with Instrument and Leaks doesn't show any problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The static analyzer understands certain cocoa conventions such as methods beginning with "new" returning a retained object pointer.

I would suggesting changing "`new_value`" in `prop.new_value` to something different.

Source: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects.operands.retained_returns

Comment: Thanks Brandon, renaming fixed the issue.